# SQL find period that contain dates of specific year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a **table** (lets call it AAA) containing 3 colums **ID,DateFrom,DateTo**

I want to write a query to return all the records that contain (even 1 day) within the period DateFrom-DateTo of a **specific year** (eg 2016).

I am using SQL Server 2005

Thank you

Comment: `I am using SQL Server 2005` - yet you've tagged the question with 2008 - is there a reason, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM AAA
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,DateFrom)=2016 OR DATEPART(YEAR,DateTo)=2016
```

Comment: Warning - this and Brahim's answer will get slow on larger datasets. If that starts to happen - you will want to go with something along the lines of Zohar's (sargable) answer.

Comment: @Bridge (and @zohar) Thanks for the tip, I didn't know. Is this method always significantly slower or only if the date fields are indexed? Brahim's answer doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: Always slower - it can't really use the index. Read up on writing [Sargable queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sargable&oldid=673974809). The general rule of thumb for writing sargable queries is that anything that manipulates the column in any way (such as using a function on it) is a no-no.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is this:

```
SELECT <columns list>
FROM AAA
WHERE DateFrom <= '2016-12-31' AND DateTo >= '2016-01-01'
```

If you have an index on `DateFrom` and `DateTo`, this query allows Sql-Server to use that index, unlike the query in Max xaM's answer.
On a small table you will probably see no difference but on a large one there can be a big performance hit using that query, since Sql-Server can't use an index if the column in the where clause is inside a function

Comment: DateFrom 01/01/2015, dateTo 01/01/2018 , Doesn't he still wants it as an output ?

Comment: Duplicating my comment on my own answer so that you see it:
Thanks for the tip, I didn't know. Is this method always significantly slower or only if the date fields are indexed?

Comment: Only for indexed columns, and noticable only when the table gets large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the following query

```
select * from Table1 
WHERE DateDiff(day,DateFrom,DateTo)>0 
      AND YEAR(DateFrom) = YEAR(DateTo)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Enjoy :D !